# How to add picture in Doxia for Markup?

Tags: maven, markdown, doxia

I am using Doxia plugin for markdown and I want to add pictures in

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                <artifactId>doxia-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>render-books</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatedDocs>${project.build.directory}/doxia</generatedDocs>
                    <books>
                        <book>
                            <directory>src/main/resources/UserGuide/markdown</directory>
                            <descriptor>src/main/resources/UserGuide/markdown/book.xml</descriptor>
                            <formats>
                                <format>
                                    <id>pdf</id>
                                </format>
                            </formats>
                        </book>
                    </books>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Then add resources:

```
       <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/images</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/doxia/images</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
```

Then in my chapter I wrote:

```
![Image of Test Image]("C:\Users\Xelian\Project\target\doxia\images\proxy.png")
```

But nothing happens? This picture is in the target path. How to specify the path in the markdown?

Comment: Why are you using such an old doxia maven plugin and mixing doxia versions (plugin 1.1.4 and markdown 1.5) Take a look http://maven.apache.org/doxia/

Comment: Because it is the las whichI found in the internet. 1.2 is from 2012 and is the latest form Maven Cnetral? Is there a plugin renaming or something like that?